# Will libraries in a makefile still be added to compilation when not specified in the preprocessor directives of the containing files?

Tags: makefile, preprocessor

Will libraries in a makefile still be added to compilation when not specified in the preprocessor directives of the containing source files? The makefile in question is listed below, I refer lF77 and lI77 to the unspecified libraries. Thanks.

**makefile:**

```
composite: maincomp.c screenio.c cscreens.c turbine.c stat.c decide.c    file.c\
          sys.c dummy.c util.c cglobal.h composite.h cscreens.h f2c.h\
          maincomp.h screenio.h turbine.h util.h makefile   gcc maincomp.c screenio.c cscreens.c turbine.c stat.c decide.c util.c\
           file.c dummy.c sys.c -I/usr/5include -L/home/boltoj/f2c/libF77\
           -lF77 -L/home/boltoj/f2c/libI77 -lI77 -L/usr/5lib -lcurses -lm\
           -o composite -g
```

Answer (score 0):

Linker only links in libraries that resolve unresolved symbols. In other words, if a library doesn't provide any symbols an object file needs, that library doesn't get linked in.

Comment: Thanks, that explains my multiple 'unresolved external symbol errors' during compilation as those libraries do not exist (they were not provided to me by the author.)